# Memory leak when opening Chrome from react native app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio-3.0

This happens only on Android 7.1 in our tests when opening a link using Chrome, intermittently. It seems to be some sort of memory leak that leads to our app beeing stopped, how can we prevent this. We are not seeing it on iOS, and not on any other of our testingphones for android or in the emulator.

```
02-12 07:54:55.429 15484-15484/myapp D/ViewRootImpl@ed30525[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
02-12 07:54:55.440 15484-15484/myapp D/ViewRootImpl@ed30525[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][720,1280] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
02-12 07:54:55.440 15484-15484/myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=157
02-12 07:54:55.955 15484-15484/myapp D/ViewRootImpl@ed30525[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
02-12 07:54:55.956 15484-15860/myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Texture is using 0.00B, count = 1
                                                                 OffscreenBuffer is using 0.00B, count = 0
                                                                 Layer is using 0.00B, count = 1
02-12 07:54:55.956 15484-15860/myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: GPU Memory Leak happened by Application!!(2 Objects) 
02-12 07:54:55.956 15484-15860/myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Below Textures or Layers was not cleared even though Application being closed.(It should be fixed by Application side)
02-12 07:54:55.956 15484-15860/myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: [Leak]Texture size is 0, 720 x 908
02-12 07:54:55.957 15484-15860/myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: [Leak]Layer size is 0, 720 x 908
02-12 07:54:55.957 15484-15860/myapp A/OpenGLRenderer: Leaked 2 GPU objects!
02-12 07:54:56.221 15484-15860/myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
02-12 07:54:56.221 15484-15860/myapp W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
02-12 07:54:56.221 15484-15860/myapp W/google-breakpad: 1.0.0
02-12 07:54:56.221 15484-15860/myapp W/google-breakpad: 42
02-12 07:54:56.221 15484-15860/myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
02-12 07:54:56.223 15484-15860/myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15860 (RenderThread)

                                                       [ 02-12 07:54:56.224  2134: 2134 W/         ]
                                                       debuggerd: handling request: pid=15484 uid=10268 gid=10268 tid=15860
```

The code for the view is which renders the view is the following:

```
    class Support extends React.Component<Props> {
  handleCall = () => {
    Linking.openURL('tel:+00000000');
  };

  handleLink = () => {
    Linking.openURL('http://www.test.com').catch((err) =>
      debug('An error occured when opening Link', err),
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MainContainer>
        <View>
          <Header {...this.props} title={_('Support')} />
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Support size={60} />
          </View>
          <ListSectionHeader
            text={_('Your support contact')}
            hasTopBorder={false}
          />
          <ListRows>
            <ListRow
              text={_('Contact')}
              rightText="Test"
              hasTopBorder={false}
            />
            <ListRow
              text={_p('Web', 'internet')}
              rightText="test.com"
              onPress={this.handleLink}
              rightIconName="ios-globe"
            />
            <ListRow
              text={_('Phone number')}
              rightText="+00000000"
              onPress={this.handleCall}
              rightIconName="ios-call"
            />
          </ListRows>
        </View>
      </MainContainer>
    );
  }
}
Support.displayName = 'tabViews/Support';

export default getWithErrorHandling(Support);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of this screen

Comment: Code for view added.

Comment: I 'm facing the exact same problem! Did you find a solution already?

Comment: Havent seen it for a while. We have updated our React version, perrhaps this fixed it?

Comment: I'm getting this on a native java app. Do you, by any chance, remember the phones / OS this crash occurred on?